# Move files from one S3 folder to another S3 folder up to certain date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to move all files from one S3 folder to another folder within the same bucket. But I would like to exclude any file within the last 15 days. Any help with python script or the `--exclude` command?

```
aws s3 mv s3://BUCKETNAME/myfolder/All_files.csv s3://BUCKETNAME/myotherfolder/All_files.csv --exclude last-fifteen-days
```

Comment: You can't do this with `exclude`. You have to iterate over all files, check their dates, and move them one by one.

Comment: Is this a one-off activity, or something you'll do regularly? If it is one-off, it could be simplest to list the contents of the source bucket and then use Excel to create a whole lot of `aws s3 mv` commands to move the files to their new destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick one but you'll still need to filter by date with wildcard.

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucketname/folder1 --recursive | \
grep '2021-10*' | \
awk '{print $4}' | \
xargs -I '{}' aws s3 mv s3://bucketname/'{}' s3://bucketname/folder2/'{}'
```